# Retrieve all BusinessUnits For an Account

Tags: java, marketing-cloud

I'm trying to use the ExactTarget SOAP-based Web Service to retrieve all the business units in my account.  I can retrieve the account and the default/parent business unit, but I can't figure out how to get the retrieve request to retrieve all the business units in my account (parent + all children business units).  I've tried to retrieve child business units individually, but that hasn't worked either.

Here's the code that returns only the default (parent) business unit:

```
    RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
        request.setObjectType("BusinessUnit");
        request.getProperties().add("AccountType");
        request.getProperties().add("ParentID");
        request.getProperties().add("BrandID");
        request.getProperties().add("PrivateLabelID");
        request.getProperties().add("ReportingParentID");
        request.getProperties().add("Name");
        request.getProperties().add("FromName");
        request.getProperties().add("BusinessName");
        request.getProperties().add("ParentName");
        request.getProperties().add("CustomerID");
        RetrieveRequestMsg requestMsg = new RetrieveRequestMsg();
        requestMsg.setRetrieveRequest(request);
    RetrieveResponseMsg responseMsg = stub.retrieve(requestMsg);
```

I get a valid response back but the results in the RetrieveResponseMsg only contains one business unit object.  When I tried to use a SimpleFilterPart to select a child BusinessUnit, the results were null.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set QueryAllAccounts to true. I'm not a Java developer but I just tested with Python. I *believe* the following code should work for Java.

```
request.QueryAllAccounts = true;
```

You can find more information here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_enterprise_20_accounts_with_the_web_services_api/

Comment: Yes,  this is the correct solution.  Thanks for that!